# Visual Studio 2010 freezes on build with particular file open

Tags: performance, visual-studio-2010, file, build

So my Visual Studio 2010 is extremely slow (and sometimes freezes) when I have a particular file open and attempt to compile and run the project. I have to open the Task Manager and kill the process for Visual Studio to regain control. If I close this file, and open any other file in the Solution Explorer in my project, Visual Studio compiles and runs the program just fine. The build succeeds, but Visual Studio just freezes after that. If I attempt to do anything in the IDE, Windows will tell me that Visual Studio is not responding. I've tried commenting out everything but the bare essentials in the file that's causing the freezing, and that didn't work. In order to get my program up and running, I have to close the file and then build the project. Visual Studio will then build and run the program in a timely manner as long as the particular file is not open. This only started a few days ago, and I haven't made any changes to the code that could have done this, nor have I updated or installed anything else onto my computer. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please don't answer your own questions in questions. Instead, use the `Add an Answer` button down below. By the way, take a __[tour]__.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this. What I did was run devenv.exe /log and looked through the log. It had the following warning in it: "The CTM file is out of date and should be deleted and rebuilt, but the file 'C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\1033\devenv.CTM' could not be deleted." I went and deleted this file, and it did the trick. Now even with that particular file open, Visual Studio builds and runs the program just fine.